# When is "improving / accepting" an edit considered too much?

Tags: discussion, editing, review-queue

I've come across a couple items in the review queue that were good edits, but they needed more.

Should I accept the edit using the <kbd>Accept</kbd> button, and then go and edit? Or should I use the <kbd>Accept and Improve</kbd> button for any and all edits I do, no matter how severe (as long as they do not change the edited content)?

If I should use the <kbd>Accept and Improve</kbd> method, is a drastic change okay? Or should I limit it to a few edits to the edit (like typos) and just make the rest of the edits myself?

Comment: Generally it is pretty much up to the reviewer. If you think it's good enough just approve it. If it needs a lot of work reject and improve. If the editor missed a few things approve and improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one goal of our edit reviews is to educate people to make better edits I tend to "accept and improve" only rather small omissions.

When someone suggests an edit where only the easy (spottable or doable) part has been done I rather use "reject and improve".